# React-Native update specific item in redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update a comment in my redux store by id, pretty sure I'm doing something wrong

```
case actionTypes.COMMENT_UPDATE:
            console.log(action.comment.id)
            console.log(action.comment.comment)
            return update(state, {selectedPhoto: {comments: {[action.comment.id]: {comment: {$set: action.comment.comment}}}}
            });
```

my state is like so 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code, hope it helps someone else

```
case actionTypes.COMMENT_UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedPhoto: {
                    ...state.selectedPhoto,
                    comments: state.selectedPhoto.comments.map((comment) => {
                        return comment.id === action.comment.id ? { ...comment, comment: action.comment.comment } : comment
                    })
                }
            };
```